# How to manage getops argument assignation

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

This is my first question.

I'm trying to make a small script with options and I'm using `getopts` to do it. The weird thing is:

The argument don't get assigned to the variable or it always enter the `if` codeblock (that seems the problem).

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

function work () {
    echo "It Works" }

function help () {
    echo "Print some help and options" }

while getopts ha:b: OPT; do
    case $OPT in
        -h)
            help
            exit
            ;;
        -a)
        OPTA=$OPTARG
        ;;
        -b)
        OPTB=$OPTARG
            ;;
        \?)
        help
            break
            ;;
    esac done

echo $OPTB

if  [[ -z $OPTB ]]; then
    echo "ERROR. Needs OPTB"
fi

if [[ -n $OPTB ]]; then
    echo "All OK untill here"
    work
fi
```

It allways prints the ERROR message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getopts` removes the "-" sign from the options.

So you need:

```
while getopts ha:b: OPT; do
    case $OPT in
        h)
            help
            exit
            ;;
        a)

 ....
```

And remember to clear your variables before calling `getopts` (`unset OPTA OPTB`) as they  may be in the environment received by your script. Also please consider the case of whether calling the script with `-b ""` is valid or not as your `[[ -z $OPTB ]]` doesn't differentiate "no `-b` option" from "`-b` option with empty argument".